# Adding a calculated field on jpa + jackson

Tags: json, hibernate, jpa, jackson, calculated-field

How to add a calculated field to an entity?

DB table

```
table person {
    id number,
    first_name varchar,
    last_name varchar,
    ...
}
```

Java entity

```
public class person {
    BigDecimal id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
...//getters and setters

    //what to add here???
    public String getFullName() {
        return firstName + " " + lastname;
    }
}
```

I tried adding @Transient, but the field is ignored when converting to json.
I tried just leaving the method there, throws an exception that the setter is missing. adding the setter throws another exception that the field does not exist in the DB.
I tried adding @Transient and @JsonPropert, but the field is ignored when converting to json.
I tried adding @Formula, but hibernate (i think) says it is not implemented.

The idea is to have a simple calculated field that is ignored by jpa/hibernate but is used by jackson.
How can I accomplish this?

**EDIT**

Example full class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FDF_PATIENT_COUNTIE")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = JSOGGenerator.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Audited
public class PatientCounty extends FgaBaseClass {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1425318521043179798L;

    private BigDecimal id;
    private County FCounties;
    private Patient patients;

    public PatientCounty() {
    }

    public PatientCounty(County FCounties, Patient patients) {
        this.FCounties = FCounties;
        this.patients = patients;
    }

    @SequenceGenerator(name="generator", sequenceName="FDF_PATIENT_COUNTIE_SEQ")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=SEQUENCE, generator="generator")
    @Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=22, scale=0)
    public BigDecimal getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(BigDecimal id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_F_COUNTIE")
    public County getFCounties() {
        return this.FCounties;
    }

    public void setFCounties(County FCounties) {
        this.FCounties = FCounties;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_FDF_PATIENT")
    public Patient getPatients() {
        return this.patients;
    }

    public void setPatients(Patient patients) {
        this.patients = patients;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you annotate fields and not getters, Hibernate will ignore your getters. I don't see why Jackson would care about `@Transient`, which is a JPA annotation and not a Jackson annotation.

Comment: I don't have a field for this. I only have a getter method. In that method I concatenate two strings...

Comment: Yes, so? If you annotate your fields, Hibernate will ignore your getters, and will thus not consider fullName as a property that is persistent.

Comment: ok, I didn't quite get what you were saying when I first read it, but it does work. That said, is there another way of doing this? these classes are generated through hibernate reverse engineering and all the annotations are on the methods. there's HUNDREDS of fields...

Comment: Jackson may consider `@Transient`, but only when using Hibernate module; and even then it is possible to configure it not to use it. But it may play a part, depending on whether Hibernate module is being used.

Comment: can you give us your real entity (to see all the annotations)? @JsonProperty only work if you use Jackson as Provider, are you sure that your deserialiser is taking Jackson as provider.